# Progress bar in notification bar while uploading image to a server in Android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am uploading image to a web server by picking the image from gallery or by capturing it using android camera.

I need to show a progress in the notification bar. I see the Facebook app does this. is there a way to find out how much has been uploaded?

My code for uploading the image to the server is :

```
public void uploadImage() {
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Image uploaded successfully",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Upload");
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to upload the captured picture?");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        testWebService(Bitmap bmp)
        finish();
        toast.show();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        dialog.cancel();

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}



public void testWebService(Bitmap bmp) {

    MarshalBase64 marshal = new MarshalBase64();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    byte[] raw = out.toByteArray();

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
        OPERATION_NAME);

    request.addProperty("image", raw);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    marshal.register(envelope);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

    try

    {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
            }

    catch (Exception exception)

    {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }

    }
```

Is there a way to find out how much has been uploaded?

Comment: I want to do the same thing capture an image from a built-in camera and send it to the server. Can I ask how you made the connection between the image from camera and the upload part? What method did you use at the web server part to receive the image?
Does the method have byte[] argument?
The method I have is one without arguments it generates a random number. So how can I make the connection between these two? Send the image and return a random number?
Please help!!
Thanks.

Comment: @jennifer : As you have solved the issue , can i know how did u get the amount of byte array that is being uploaded ?

Comment: Junaid i used Multipart form upload on Android 
http://www.17od.com/2010/02/18/multipart-form-upload-on-android/

Comment: An answer below is link-only, and may be deleted by the Review Queue. [It is here](http://androidpeople.com/android-progress-dialog-style) in order to preserve it.

Answer (score 3):

This is useful link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView

Now use Progress Bar in your custom layout for your Notification.

This code is for tracing download. As this you can check upload status, start this Async task in a service to upload and update progress bar accordingly

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

Comment: How can i trace the  % of image being uploaded ??

Comment: This code is for tracing download.... As this you can check upload status, start this Async task in a service to upload and update progress bar accordingly

Comment: I need to trace how much byte arry is being uploaded over a webservice.. the progress of byte arry transferred over soap service

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the classes you're using to make your SOAP calls, but a common way of accomplishing upload progress with the Apache Commons HttpClient is to provide your own FilterOutputStream subclass that simply makes a callback to a specified listener every time part of the stream is read out. You just need to override the write() methods:

```
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        transferred += len;
        progressHandler.handleProgress(ProgressDirection.Send, len, transferred, expectedLength);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        progressHandler.handleProgress(ProgressDirection.Send, 1, ++transferred, expectedLength);
    }
```

Of course, you can only use this method if your HTTP library allows you to provide the entire body (or at least a large portion) of your HTTP request as an OutputStream.